# Grails Rendering 404, 403, 500 errors as JSON from ErrorController

Tags: json, grails, error-handling, http-status-code-404

Running Grails 2.4.3, I created an ErrorController with methods to handle 403, 404, and 500 errors. I have GSPs for the 3 methods, and they render fine, but I also wanted to have them return JSON responses if the request uses the '.json' extension. My code as written below, only returns the gsp versions regardless of the request type, so, even requests with the '.json' extension are rendering the gsp. How do I get the JSON versions to work?

The UrlMappings:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/" (controller: "home", action: "index")
        ...

        "403" (controller: "error", action: "forbidden")
        "404" (controller: "error", action: "notFound")
        "500" (controller: "error", action: "index")
    }
}
```

The ErrorController:

```
class ErrorController {
    def forbidden() {
        withFormat {
            json {
                render(contentType: "text/json") { response ERROR: [code: 403, msg: "Access Denied."] }
            }
            '*' { render(view: 'forbidden') }
        }
    }
    def notFound() {
        withFormat {
            json {
                render(contentType: "text/json") { response ERROR: [code: 404, msg: "Page not found."] }
            }
            '*' { render(view: 'notFound') }
        }
    }
    def index() {
        withFormat {
            json {
                render(contentType: "text/json") { response ERROR: [code: 500, msg: "Internal Server Error."] }
            }
            '*' { render(view: 'internalServer') }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have to throw an exception after `response.sendError(403)` in home controller, then error handling works with `withFormat`. This looks weird. A better way will be handling errors and exception with [this convention](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#controllerExceptionHandling), if at all viable.

Comment: I am confused. You say I would need to 'throw an exception after response.sendError(403) in home controller' Can you include and example? And then you say 'This looks weird' - are you referring to 'throw an exception after response.sendError(403) in home controller' or my code? Also, I don't understand how the pattern you refer to as the 'better way' would fit with my code. Can you give an example of that? Why is it only delivering gsp version?

Comment: My bad. My point was that it works the way you have written only when we throw an Exception after `sendError()`. I do have an example which I was trying out when saw this question, which I am unable to find out. :(